Errors "Not available for deploy for this organization" and "Invalid type: AgentWork" when try to create a unlocked package
I've recently started working with Salesforce. I've made an omni-channel application and would like to create an Unlocked package that would deploy my classes, lwc components, and omni configuration. I'm not sure if all these omni files can be made available via the package (queue, routing config, services channels, presence status, presence configuration).
In this context, I'm trying to create a version of the package using
sf package version create --package 0H.....  --wait 10 .

I'm getting these errors:
 - (service channel) queue_Cases: Not available for deploy for this organization
 - (routing config) config_Queue_1: Not available for deploy for this organization
 - (user presence status)  queue_Available: Not available for deploy for this organization
 - (presence user config) Config_queue: Not available for deploy for this organization
- (apex class to run a trigger logic on the AgentWork) MyClassAgentWorkTriggerHandler: Invalid type: AgentWork
- MyClassAgentWorkTriggerHandler: Invalid type: AgentWork
- MyClassAgentWorkTriggerHandler: Variable does not exist: newOppMap. (this variable I used to cast the object to AgentWork on the trigger handler)
- MyClassAgentWorkTriggerHandler: Invalid type: AgentWork
- (test class) MyClassAgentWorkTriggerTest: Invalid type: AgentWork
- MyClassAgentWorkTriggerTest: DML requires SObject or SObject list type: AgentWork
- MyClassAgentWorkTrigger: Invalid type: Schema.AgentWork
- (custom permission set) My_User_Permissions: In field: apexClass - no ApexClass named MyClassAgentWorkTriggerHandler found

I was wondering if I could upload something related to the omni-channel via the package. And what could be the problem in recognizing the SalesForce AgentWork class itself. The code has almost 90% code coverage, everything works but I can't overcome these errors to create the package. Does anyone have any ideas?

You'll want to check out the Metadata Coverage Report. As far I can tell, at the time of this answer, AgentWork isn't even listed as a Metadata type that you can use at all, much less in a managed package. You might be able to get away with this if you move to an org-dependent unlocked package, but keep in mind that this means you'll need manual setup in each org before you can install the package.

Thank you, I noted only now I had a several limitation working on unlocked package. I will do some changes on my code to avoid use the AgentWork class.

I still need to see which options I can use to deliver omni queue setup after the package installation.
